# YA book about a caveman in modern day

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I read this book when I was pretty young about a caveman who survived till modern day. The only details I can think of are that there was a boy who had some bread and cheese. Think it was based in France. The caveman made cave paintings.

It was written pre-90's.

Comment: Do you have any more information? Like when was it written?

Comment: Not really. I know it was written pre 1990's. Nothing more conclusive than that.

Answer (score 6):

Could it have been [Stig Of The Dump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stig_of_the_Dump)?

It was set in England though...

[image]

Comment: Sounds like an interesting read, but I don't believe that was the book. I distinctly remember references to France.

Answer (score 0):

As per this answer to another question about a caveman in the modern day, might it be [*Child in Darkness*](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/195307674) by Robert Hill?

[image: Front cover of Child in Darkness]

> A loner boy that I could relate to as a child, loved to wonder off and explore. One day sitting in a tree his apple dropped and rolled to across the grass and right up against the closed off mine entrance he so clearly was not to enter. He notices a blue arm, clammy skinny and odd reach for the apple and disappear into the mine.