# A boy that made friends with a cave boy

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for a book we read in high school. I have no rememberance of the name but the front cover was something like a tiny hand with long black nails holding a red apple. It was about a cave boy who had interactions with a boy on the outside. They got attached but I think their languages differed so had difficulty speaking. It was a very touching story ... just cannot seem to remember anything more that'll be of assistance in finding it. Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Exchange.  Can you include any more details? Do you have any idea of the author or date when this book was published?

Comment: possibly related to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/56891/ya-book-about-a-caveman-in-modern-day/56893#56893

Answer (score 9):

This is probably *Stig of the Dump*, by Clive King.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stig_of_the_Dump):

> [Barney] falls over the edge of an old chalk pit close to Barney's grandparents' house he tumbles down through the roof of Stig's den. When he looks round, there's Stig- apparently a 'caveman', with shaggy, black hair and bright black eyes.

Comment: Assuming this turns out to be the right answer, it's neither scifi, nor fantasy.

Comment: @Richard - How so? Time travel occurs in the plot, and is the reason the "caveman" ends up in modern England to begin with.

Comment: @Jonah - No, you're right. I was misremembering that Stig was just feral, not an actual, factual caveperson.

Answer (score 8):

The book is called [*Child in Darkness*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2116610.Child_In_Darkness) by Robert Hill, a South African novelist.

A children's novel in which a boy discovers a blind, pale creature-like being living in a cave and begins to interact, feed and eventually befriend it.

[image]

Comment: The cover seems a good match, as does the description